# Google onEdit trigger Exception: When &quot;wait .....&quot;, do not edit

Tags: google-apps-script

For some people who installed my To-do list plugin which I published on Google Workspace MarketPlace, they have the an error Exception: When "wait .....", do not edit. The message is not from my scripts. The error stack points to the script "SpreadsheetApp.flush()". I googled and could not find any information about this error. Does anyone know what this error means and how to avoid it?